# How to throttle onLocationChanged in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, location

I want to update the location of a user after every 10 minutes. The `onLocationChanged` works fine, even when the app is in the background. However, it keeps throwing the location details when location changes. I want it to run a method `_getCurrentLocationtoServer()` after 10minutes.

```
location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData cLoc) {
      currentLocation = cLoc;
      _getCurrentLocationtoServer();
    });

void _getCurrentLocationtoServer() async{
//code to send to server
}
```

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/location package.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call _getCurrentLocationtoServer() inside onLocationChanged. Just assign the currentLocation value.
Now, make a new

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 10), () => _getCurrentLocationtoServer());
```

This runs periodically and sends currentLocation value to the server every 10 minutes. Make sure the currentLocation value is not null before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the interval of the `location` by calling `changeSettings` and set the proper interval:

> interval will set the desired interval for active location updates, in
> milliseconds (only affects Android).

```
location.changeSettings(interval: 1000 * 60 * 10); // 10 mins
```